# Security Configuration Wizard or Security Compliance Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

When securing Windows 2008 R2 do I need to use both the Security Configuration Wizard and Security Compliance Manager or  does the SCM do everything the SCW does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend starting with SCM and creating your baseline GPOs from there, then customizing by hand. SCM has a lot of info on each setting if you don't know them all by heart yet!